# Python Flask App - failed building wheel for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple python flask application. I have deployed a very similar app in the past with all the same requirements in the requirements.txt folder.

While trying to push my repo to heroku using 'git push heroku master', heroku does its thing and eventually gives the following errors:

```
remote:        ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
remote:        Successfully built numpy
remote:        Failed to build pandas
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to isitdry.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/isitdry.git
```

So there is something about pandas that it doesn't like.

Here is what my requirements.txt looks like:

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.2
pandas==1.1.2                 # here is the problem!
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.10
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Is there something wrong with my version of pandas? Can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using latest pandas version. `pandas==1.2.4` works fine for me. You will have to update numpy as well, as it might create compatibility issues. Update numpy to `numpy==1.20.3`.

Comment: these two worked with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall pandas using
2. pip uninstall pandas
3. pip install pandas==1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a Dockerfile and I had to use the base image of `python:3.10` instead of `python:3.10-alpine`.